# ListView item layout issue - combining ImageView(s) with TextView(s)

Tags: java, android, layout, view

I have a ListView with custom Item view. The item layout consists of ImageView, 3xTextViews, and 3x small ImageView (code below). The problem is that I want the all ImageViews to be always visible and force TextViews to adjust their widths and the texts to break into multiline correctly. Here is how it looks like:

[image: Layout problem]

Below is the layout item xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="85dp" android:layout_height="85dp" android:id="@+id/imageView1" ></ImageView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"  android:paddingLeft="3dp">
        <TextView android:text="aa24324234" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="bb22222" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="italic" ></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="ccvvvvbb" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="italic"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom|right">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Jopek"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3 items" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Modified: 24-02-2012 20:11 asd asd asd a asdad asd " >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In xml view 3 images looks like they are at bottom of the screen but in run time it looks perfect.Try it !

Answer (score 0):

try to decrease the size of textview in  portrait layout

Answer (score 0):

Use a Relative layout for the main root layout of the list row and first set the ImageView at the right and one imageview which you are displaying folder icon place it to the left side of the row and now set the textview(s) to the left of the ImageView(s) and right of the ImageView(folder).